# Regex to get data between HTML tags (tags have properties)

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

First off, I know it's bad practice to use Regex for HTML parsing, but I'm developing a mobile app, so size and simplicity are important. Also, the requirement is pretty straight forward.

HTML tags: `<td width=100>Capture This</td>` (The tags can be td/span/etc, same for the property e.g. height/style/etc.)

What Regex should I use to get the part "Capture This"?

Answer (score 1):

`Regex` is a [poor option for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583), in particular from different sources.

I suggested using a purpose built parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com) instead.

> What is exactly the Html Agility Pack (HAP)?
>
> This is an agile HTML parser that builds a read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is a .NET code library that allows you to parse "out of the web" HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to what proposes System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or streams).

The source download comes with a bunch of example projects so you can see how to use it.

Comment: @antikbd - You can always get the source of the HAP and compile it for WP7. Regardless - from the linked page: "This release includes versions of Html Agility Pack for .NET 2.0 - 4.5, Silverlight 4-5, **Windows Phone 7-7.1** and Windows 8 Metro."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match a certain element, which can have attributes but no child nodes, use

```
/<td(?:\s[^<>]+)?>([^<>]*)<\/td>/
```

and get the captured group.